# Calculate 3x3 matrix to give lowest difference for data set

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix

I'm building an application where I need to compare found data with the actual data it should be.

I have 5 sets of data, each with 3 variables a,b,c.
Let matrix A be a 3x1 matrix with data a,b,c which represents the actual data.
Let matrix B be a 3x3 matrix with unknown data that needs to be calculated.
Let matrix C be a 3x1 matrix with found data a,b,c.

The equation A = B.C needs to be solved so that it gives the lowest difference for the 5 datasets.

How would I start with solving this? Do I just have to start with some numbers in B and try new ones each iteration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me see if I can restate the problem to answer your question:

You have 5 sets of data: $y_{i}$, $x_{i}$ such that for each $i = 1, \ldots, 5$, $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$ are both 3 by 1 vectors. You also have a 3 by 3 matrix $B$ that is supposed to relate $x_{i}$ to $y_{i}$ via:

$$y_{i} = Bx_{i} $$

Is this formulation correct?

If so, the proper methods for solving this sort of problem use [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

One linear regression method is [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)(OLS). OLS will find a solution to the overdetermined set of equations:

$$[y_{1}, \ldots, y_{5}] = B \cdot [x_{1}, \ldots, x_{5}]$$

with minimum residual; that is, it minimizes the sum of squared distances between the data $y_{i}$ and the predictions $Bx_{i}$, hence "least squares". This sum of squared distances is $\sum_{i=1}^{5}\|y_{i} - Bx_{i}\|^{2}$ (the norm used is a 2-norm).

For convenience, define the 3 by 5 matrices $X$ and $Y$ by:

$$Y = [y_{1}, \ldots, y_{5}],$$
$$X = [x_{1}, \ldots, x_{5}],$$

so we are finding a solution to the overdetermined system of equations

$$Y = BX$$

with minimum sum-of-squared distances. This next part is important:

*The notation I've used to describe your problem is the transpose of what the Wikipedia article on ordinary least squares uses.* So if you try to compare everything, you're going to have to transpose every matrix.

Using some algebra, the value of $B$ that minimizes the sum of squared distances is

$$B = (XX^{T})^{-1}XY^{T};$$

you can check the dimensions of each matrix to see that $B$ is 3 by 3.

**Do not calculate $B$ this way.**

Calculating matrix inverses directly is usually bad for a variety of reasons; why it is bad is out of the scope of the question. If you need a matrix inverse, it's usually better to solve the system of equations related to that inverse.

A better way to calculate $B$ would be to solve the related linear system

$$XX^{T}B = XY^{T}.$$

This system of equations is called the *normal equations* (plural, because the system of equations is referred to as a group).

**Do not calculate $B$ using the normal equations either.**

Solving the normal equations is not usually a good idea because this system of equations can be ill-conditioned, which will degrade the accuracy of $B$.

An even better way to calculate $B$ would be to use QR decomposition.

Let $X^{T} = [Q_{1}, Q_{2}]([R_{1}, 0])^{T}$, obtained from a QR decomposition. Using the methods outlined [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs3220-s12/notes/lec10.pdf),

$$B = R_{1}^{-1}Q_{1}^{T}Y^{T},$$

so I would solve the linear system

$$R_{1}B = Q_{1}^{T}Y^{T}.$$

This last method should give you what you want (assuming I didn't make any mistakes during my lunch break).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what my problem is. I will look at the Wikipedia to see if I can make it work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be of great help to me. I've read the Wikipedia page about lineair regression but this is a lot easier to understand.